# Error while transferring data from sqlite to elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Hello to all members of the forum

There is a script that takes data from the db.sqlite database and transfers it to the elasticsearch database, which falls into an error related to the ContextManager, it does not reach how to solve.

let's get it in order:

there is a db.sqlite database

there is a running elasticsearch server on the locale - checked it works

the script takes data from the database and pushes it to the elasticsearch database

elasticsearch prepared for push, created index with correct schema

here is the script code: https://dpaste.org/TFNd

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D: \ Yandex_Midl \ p1 \ src \ script.py", line 240, in <module>
start.load (index)
File "D: \ Yandex_Midl \ p1 \ src \ script.py", line 221, in load
writers = self.load_writers_names ()
File "D: \ Yandex_Midl \ p1 \ src \ script.py", line 153, in load_writers_names
for writer in self.conn.execute ('' 'SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM writers' ''):
AttributeError: '_GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

as far as I know, the problem is hidden in the function: conn_context

but I can't figure out how to solve it.

can anyone help me

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is in this function:

```
def conn_context(db_path: str):
​
    print("def conn_context")
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    # yield conn
    # conn.close()
    try:
        yield conn
    except:
        print("exception")
​
    conn.close()
```

Nothing hidden really, you are asigning the returning value of this function to connn in this line:

```
connn =  conn_context(db_path)
```

But what you are returning is a generator object because of the yielding, not the connection. Yield is for another purpose. Pro tip: that yield will not raise an exception so no try required.

You must return conn, and close it when your script ends, not inside this function.

```
def conn_context(db_path: str):​
    print("def conn_context")
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    return conn
    


connn =  conn_context(db_path)
# Do your stuff
connn.close()
```